# Python Hall Sensor Monitor - Too High CPU Usage

Tags: python, embedded, embedded-linux

I'm doing a project where I need to monitor several hall sensors for a position encoding. The logic is pretty simple, but the digital signal is fast: it may have up to 350 position changes per second.

I was hoping I could simply write a hall sensor monitor program watching the GPIOs but it appears that these programs consume quite a bit of CPU if I monitor at the necessary frequency. I had hoped suspending the CPU between every poll would help, but it doesn't seem to make much difference.

Here's the polling loop from what I'm currently doing. It "works", but the CPU usage is far too high. I'm running this on a process that shares the "position" variable with other processes on a memory-mapped file.

```html
REFRESH_RATE = .0005

while True:
    new_p1_state = GPIO.input(hall_p1)
    new_p2_state = GPIO.input(hall_p2)

    if new_p1_state != p1_state or new_p2_state != p2_state:
        if p1_state == GPIO.HIGH:
            if new_p2_state == GPIO.HIGH:
                position -= 1
            else:
                position += 1
        else:
            if new_p2_state == GPIO.LOW:
                position -= 1
            else:
                position += 1

        p1_state = new_p1_state
        p2_state = new_p2_state

    time.sleep(REFRESH_RATE)
```

Can anybody recommend a more efficient way to do this? Should I avoid python and use something faster? If so what?

Comment: Can you share any information on how long GPIO.input() typically takes per call? Also why is the refresh rate set so much faster than the potential maximum of 350 per second?

Comment: What hardware are you using?

Comment: Why is the CPU usage too high? Do you have any requirements against it? How high is it? Did you consider to use interrupts?

Comment: You are asking more of `sleep()` (and probably Python) than it can deliver. Whether this code is plausible depends on the platform also.  You probably need an RTOS and not Python.  It is not so much an issue of "faster", that one of deterministic behaviour.  You should probably use the sensors to drive an interrupt or a timer/counter.

Comment: @Tagli Jetson nano

Comment: @the_busybee it’s 35% per hall sensor, I have 2. I could probably reduce it by interleaving them and trying to optimize, but it needs to be much lower to leave CPU for other things and I think the approach needs to be radically different. I’ll read up on interrupts, that’s probably what I need

Comment: @VMatic. I toyed with the refresh rate, I could reduce it a bit but not enough to make a material difference. The 350/s is nonlinear I think it’s faster at times

Comment: I tried using the python GPIO interrupt lib: GPIO.add_event_detect(...). It was unable to keep up with the hall sensor signals, even if I slowed the device down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong hardware & software for the job. Jetson Nano can be considered as a full featured PC. As I understand, it's suitable for high level algorithms, image processing and neural network evaluation. Bare metal programming does not make much sense for this kind of devices, hence you have Linux running on it. You need to be aware that in the presence of a non real-time operating system, you can't get reliable delay times.

Reading a quadrature encoder is low level task with strict hard real-time requirements. For this, you need microcontrollers (like PIC, AVR, ARM Cortex M), C/C++, bare-metal programming or an RTOS, and preferably dedicated hardware which is capable of reading quadrature encoders directly.

Polling input pins isn't the correct way of interfacing encoders. Keep it in mind that you need to poll the pins much faster than the expected pulse frequency. In microcontrollers, you use interrupts instead which saves you from polling. Even interrupts can't keep up with high resolution & fast turning encoders. When interrupts don't suffice, you need dedicated encoder interfacing hardware which counts pulses automatically for you.

The best thing you can do is picking a microcontroller and outsourcing the encoder counting job to it. As your encoder resolution is low, you don't need special quadrature interface hardware modules. You can just pick an Arduino and make it count pulses. Then your Jetson Nano can query Arduino using serial port, I2C or SPI to retrieve the up-to-date pulse count.

Comment: Sadly, I'm afraid you have the right answer - I selected the Nano for high-level algorithms, and was hopeful it could handle these encoders too to keep the BOM simple. Python clearly isn't up to the task, I may try C or an RTOS (RTOS is available for the Jetson, though I'm afraid it may be an unfavorable tradeoff) as a last resort before redesigning with extra circuitry to handle these encoders.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give a follow-up. I was able to rewrite this  as an interrupt-based kernel driver. It  works much better than the python version, but still isn't good enough - the quadrature counter misses events and drifts  when the device is pushed too hard.

I'm now trying to apply the PREEMPT-RT patch to enable full realtime preemption to the linux kernel. Hopefully this will get me what I need without a separate microcontroller.